# What's the $T$ around a candle?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, pressure, temperature, combustion

I think most of you have already heard of the candle lift/elevator. It's a funny experiment that is easy to perform too. If you don't know what I'm talking about I would recommend you to watch the following video and you'll know immediately what I mean.

[Here's a 1:30 minute example on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A_kJQFT_pyw&ab_channel=WorldofEngineering)

Here's my short explanation: You take a tea light and place it in a bowl lightly filled with water. Then you take a beaker and place it upside down on the bowl covering the burning the light. What happens is that the candle goes out and the water is rising within the beaker to a way higher level than the water level around the beaker is. That's why it's called candle "elevator/lift" because it raises the water. I hope you can understand my explanation.

What I'm trying is to calculate the average temperature of the air around the tea light before the beaker had been placed on it considering the fact that air is an ideal gas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Average temperature is pretty hard to nail down, because it depends on lots of different things. The chemical reaction for burning a long-chain hydrocarbon is$\newcommand{\ignore}[1]{\color{lightgray}{{#1}\times{}}}$

$$
\ignore{\frac{3n+1}{2}}\mathrm{O_2} + \mathrm{H(CH_2)_\mathit{n} H}
\to
\ignore n\mathrm{CO_2} + \ignore{(n+1)}\mathrm{H_2O}
$$

A [quick search suggests](https://www.thenakedscientists.com/articles/questions/how-many-watts-burning-candle) that the right order-of-magnitude estimate for a candle flame is about $\ignore{0.8}10^2\,\rm W$.  When I do the experiment in my kitchen, the candle burns for about $\ignore{2}10^1\,\rm s$, and then the gas volume in my half-liter drinking glass decreases by about seventy-five milliliters. Air [has a constant-pressure heat capacity](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/air-properties-d_156.html) of about $\ignore{1.0}10^0\rm\,kJ / kg\,K$. Since air [has a density of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_of_air) about $\ignore{1.2}10^{-3}\rm\,kg/\ell$, my half-liter of air has mass of roughly half a gram, and the kilojoule of released heat should raise its temperature by about a thousand kelvin.

Which is *clearly* wrong. Instead, nearly all of the heat is going into liquefying and then vaporizing the wax.  The air above the candle certainly gets hot, which you can verify by holding the palm of your hand directly above the flame.  But exactly how hot is going to depend not only on the ratio of heat transfer to the air versus to the wax, which in principle is calculable, but also on how you happen to enclose the candle, how much the air in the glass is heated before you trap it, et cetera.  That's a time-dependent computational fluid dynamics problem.

If we go backwards, and attribute my observed 15% volume decrease on a 15% change in temperature, that tells you the average air temperature should have risen from about 300 K to about 350 K.  That tells you the gram of air absorbed about fifty joules of heat, or 5% of the heat produced by the candle.  That seems reasonable.

Sometimes in the winter, memes go around which suggest setting a tealight under a small upside-down terra-cotta flowerpot to make a small "room heater."  I have tried this.  My flowerpots got hot to the touch, but not unbearable.  I didn't do thermometry, but I would compare the temperature of such a "heater" to the temperature of a [sodium acetate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_acetate) [heating pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heating_pad), which heats up to about 330 K as it solidifies.

Contrary to another answer, I would *not* attribute the volume change to vapor molecules. [A candle flame reduces oxygen concentration from 21% to about 15%](https://boards.straightdope.com/t/whats-the-residual-oxygen-concentration-in-a-jar-candle-after-a-flame-out/947119).  If the oxygen were simply removed from the air, I would expect the water to be drawn up while the flame was burning; however, the volume decrease begins rather suddenly once the flame goes out.  The stoichiometry suggests instead that roughly $3n$ oxygen molecules should turn into roughly $4n$ molecules of carbon dioxide and water vapor, where $n$ is the number of carbons in the hydrocarbon chain.  I didn't notice the water level *drop* while the candle was still burning, suggesting the chemical changes to the gas-phase volume are negligible.  This is bolstered by [the candle-power link from above](https://www.thenakedscientists.com/articles/questions/how-many-watts-burning-candle), which estimates that a candle consumes wax at a few milligrams per second.  The changes in gas-particle number are only a few percent of the total number of gas molecules: not enough to explain a 15% effect.

To actually *measure* the temperature above a tealight, you would want to do a more patient experiment than I did.  First, rig a setup where you can suspend a trap for the hot exhaust (such as a drinking glass) above the tealight for a long-ish time.  The trap will eventually reach a steady-state temperature which is closer to the air above the tealight than to the room-temperature air outside of your trap.  Then when you seal the trap with water underneath, you'll see an immediate decrease in the gas volume as the gas is forced to interact with the water.

Answer (score 2):

This answer was written after your comment average student-

I excuse your judgement, since I looked at two more video for kids, trying to explain the rising, the explanations are wrong, sorry, not every youtube video is right! The first video you posted is ok. It is true, in the first moment the air under the glas is hotter so the wwater inside goes a little down, if it is very shallow outside a little bit of air may come out. But the rising of the water inside does not come from cooling, which would be very slow, but from the consuming of the 20% oxygen in the air inside.
if you repeat your own experiment but have the water outside be at least 1cm high or more, no air will come out.The rising of the water inside is very fast, so it can not come from slow cooling.

Comment: The consuming of the oxygen and the following condesing of the water vapor is responsible for around 7 percent of the water rise. (You'll get this value by calculating the burning reaction of wax.) The rest of the rise is really being caused by air escaping. As noted in my comment I do really recommend you to search for the experiment and you'll see lots of good explanations.

Answer (score -1):

The water rise in the beaker is mostly because the candle flame consumes the oxygen in the air (more precisely, hydrocarbons in the candle combine with oxygen to produce carbon dioxide and water). Before the beaker is placed on the candle, the heat from the candle flame will be rapidly dissipated by convection. Once the beaker is placed on the candle, then the candle can only burn for a short time before all of the oxygen inside the beaker is used up. So it will not burn for long enough to significantly heat the air inside the beaker (and you would need a temperature difference of at least 30 degrees C to produce a noticeable change in air volume due to temperature). Therefore I don't think the temperature of the air inside the beaker can have a significant effect on the level of the water.

Comment: Indeed the chemical aspect plays a role in the experiment. But the major reason is the physical aspect because air is escaping of the beaker.

Comment: No, no air is escaping, how should it? the water around the beaker does not let it through.  Thats exactly the purpose of the water around the beaker! If you do the experiment, you can see that no air is coming out.

Comment: I see you've no idea about this. Next time before you're sharing wrong information with other people I would highly recommend you to search a bit in the internet about the problem. If you search for "Candle lift experiment" you'll immediately see on every website how wrong you're.
Also I did the experiment and there's air coming out. Because the candle heats the air in  the beaker and higher temperature results in bigger volume. That's something that even me, a physics newbie know.

Comment: @Average_Student203 The expansion of the air inside the beaker is very small. To expand the volume of air by as much as 10% you would have to increase T by 10%, which is about 30 degrees C. If the air temperature increased by 30 degrees then the glass would fell hot. Any physical effect due to the expansion of the air is insignificant compared to the reduction in the volume of air due to combustion. Don't believe everything you see on YouTube.

Comment: This answer is wrong. In candle combustion, gaseous oxygen combines with long-chain hydrocarbons $\rm (CH_2)_n$ to make carbon dioxide and water vapor. There are more vapor molecules after the combustion than before, so your suggestion that consumption of oxygen should reduce the pressure is incorrect. In the limit where the hydrocarbon chains are very long, the number density of vapor-phase molecules increases by a third.

Comment: @rob Indeed the consuption of the oxygen is responsible for a part of the reduced pressure in the end as the vapor molecules condese as the air cools down what results in an around 1700 times smaller volume. This effect is reponsible for a volume reduction of around 7% depending on n of the wax.  But I agree with you, the answer is wrong. Do you have an idea how to solve my question?